# Is there a correct way to make Delphi designer see published properties of form and work with inherited dfm code in same time?

Tags: delphi, dfm

I got own hierarchy of forms: `TFORM->TKCustomForm->TKObjectForm->TFSObjectForm.`
TForm – standard Delphi class.
TKCustomForm – implement basic logic of my application forms (debugging, logging, resizing, etc.). No DFM changing. DFM Code:

```
object KCustomForm: TKCustomForm
  Caption = 'KCustomForm'
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  ...
end
```

TKObjectForm - implement basic logic of dialog forms of application. Add custom published properties and events. Also add visual components (bottom panel with buttons ok, cancel, apply). DFM code looks like:

```
inherited KObjectForm: TKObjectForm
  Caption = 'KObjectForm'
  ...
  object pnlBottom: TKMovePanel    
    ...
    object pnlButtons: TKMovePanel
       object btnOK: TKButton
       ..
       end
      object btnCancel: TKButton
      ..
      end
      object btnApply: TKButton
      ..
      end
    end
  end
  object DataSource: TDataSource
    Left = 184
    Top = 152
  end
end
```

TFSObjectForm – implement support of FastScript Engine. No dfm changes. DFM looks like this:

```
inherited FSObjectForm: TFSObjectForm
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
end
```

All these files are in package. All works as expected, except I cannot see additional properties and events. I must every time set it manually in sources.

I find out that this problem can be fixed by using `RegisterCustomModule` method. It’s works fine if it used for showing published properties of one formtype or frametype, but for whole hierarchy it’s works in very strange way.

In `Register` method of package I add registration of all types by `RegisterNoIcon([TKCustomForm, TKObjectForm, TFSObjectForm, TKIndepForm, TFSIndepForm]);`

When I use `RegisterCustomModule(TKCustomForm, TCustomModule);` - it’s change DFM code in KObjectForm from `inherited KObjectForm` to `object KObjectForm` and nothing happens.

When I use `RegisterCustomModule(TKObjectForm, TCustomModule);` - it’s change DFM code in FSObjectForm from `inherited FSObjectForm` to `object FSObjectForm`, shows me additional properties in designer, but remove additional panel from form.

When I use `RegisterCustomModule(TFSObjectForm, TCustomModule);` - nothing happens. DFM code same in whole hierarchy, bottom panel with buttons appears, but additional properties still missing in TFSObjectForm and all accessors. I even try to republish properties from `TKObjectForm` in `TFSObjectForm`  but it’s does not work.

How can I add components in dfm and make published properties visible in same parent class?